# упорядочить значения в массиве

Tags: php

У меня есть массив, который содержит домены

```
array(
"yandex.ru",
"mail.ru",
"mail.ru",
"yandex.ru",
"gmail.com",
"rambler.ru",
"mail.ru",
)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы массив был перемешан таким образом, чтобы при переборе домены находились один за одним без повторов и, при этом, все были в равной степени максимально удалены друг от друга. Такое возможно ?

например:

```
array(
"yandex.ru",
"mail.ru",
"gmail.com",
"rambler.ru",
"yandex.ru",
"mail.ru",
"mail.ru", - тут допускается повтор, т.к больше доменов нет для формирования списка
)
```

мне это нужно, чтобы при рассылке на email, письмо отправлялось по очереди на разные домены, чтобы избежать возможных банов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть массив:

```
$a = array(
  "yandex.ru",
  "mail.ru",
  "mail.ru",
  "yandex.ru",
  "gmail.com",
  "rambler.ru",
  "mail.ru",
);
```

Фильтруем его так:

```
$b = array_unique($a);
```

И получаем массив уникальных значений. Теперь в `$b` у нас:

```
$b = array(
  "yandex.ru",
  "mail.ru",
  "gmail.com",
  "rambler.ru",
);
```

Теперь запускаем цикл по `$b`. В каждой итерации цикла берем домен из `$b` и ищем его в `$a`. Если нашли в `$a`, посылаем письмо и вычеркиваем этот домен из `$a`. Если не нашли в `$a`, то вычеркиваем этот домен из `$b`. Если дошли до конца `$b`, а `$a` еще не пустое, то снова запускаем цикл по `$b`... и тд пока не опустеет `$a`.

- Под вычеркиванием подразумевается `unset`.
- Под поиском подразумевается `array_search`.